# HTML image-link formatting

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, formatting

I'm working on a html only webpage, and I am having some issues correctly formatting my social-media links. I have a fixed position div that is 48 x 190, and within it I'd like to put 4 different social media icons which link to their respective pages. I was able to set up the div correctly in css styling, and I was able to insert the images into the correct position just fine. However, as soon as I added the link tag to the image, it all broke. The formatting of the image seemed to change just by adding the link to it, and they now took up all this extra space around themselves, went outside the borders of the div, and refused to be properly centered. Why is adding a link to the image breaking the formatting in such a strange way, and how can I fix it so it remains formatted how I want even after the link is added?

Thanks!

Comment: I just hope you DIDN'T used <img href="#" />.

Answer (score 1):

have you set the border of your images to 0 ? When inside a link, browsers put a 1px border to images if this value is not set in the CSS.

If that is not the problem, posting your code (see jsFiddle for example) could help

Answer (score 0):

I guess, the issue is related to the different size (in pixels) of icons, that cause to increase div and distrub the UI. I have also used Image-Links as following and it works fine. First ensure your icon size.

```
<a href="javascript: showPopup();" id="groupEdit" class="link">
<img src="/images/redPencil.png" title="Update">
</a>
```